# Python Insert a list into a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

How do I insert a word to the end of each item in the list and make them as list itself?

Expected output:

```
a = [("a","TEST"),("b","TEST"),("c","TEST"),("d","TEST"),("e","TEST")]
```

I have tried a lot of ways but no luck getting that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a tuple with the item and the desired word:

```
word = "TEST"
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
new_a = [(i, word) for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'TEST'), ('b', 'TEST'), ('c', 'TEST'), ('d', 'TEST'), ('e', 'TEST')]
```

Alternatively, using `map`:

```
new_a = list(map(lambda x: (x, "TEST"), a))
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, is there any way to eliminate the space between 'a', and 'TEST'? I need to unpack it for the classifier function

Comment: @KennyC the space is natural Python syntax. `('a', 'TEST')` is equivalent to `("a","TEST")`.

Comment: Don't use map. List comprehensions are more pythonic

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` module like below (but the solution to go with should be [Ajax1234's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200384/4575071) one using tuple in a list comprehension):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
res = list(zip_longest(l, ['TEST'], fillvalue='TEST'))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[('a', 'TEST'), ('b', 'TEST'), ('c', 'TEST'), ('d', 'TEST'), ('e', 'TEST')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
new_a = zip(a, ["TEST"] * len(a))
```

output:

```
[('a', 'TEST'), ('b', 'TEST'), ('c', 'TEST'), ('d', 'TEST'), ('e', 'TEST')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very hip, but similar to other common languages:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
b = []

for x in a:
    b.append ( (x, 'TEST'))

a = b

print a
```

Comment: maybe add two lists inst the solution